# Facebook Like Box on iPhone with jQTouch

Tags: iphone, facebook, iframe, facebook-like, jqtouch

Is there a better way to integrate the facebook like box in an iphone jQTouch mobile site than using the iframe code? Ie:

```
 <div id="facebook">
   <div class="toolbar">
   <h1 class='logo'>My site</h1>
   <a class="back" href="#">Back</a>
   </div>

   <div class="facebook">
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%pagename&amp;width=320&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;connections=10&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=587" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height:587px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
   </div>

 </div>
```

The iframe on the iPhone also doesn't know you are logged in through your facebook iphone app. Is there any way to integrate that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that there is no way your website can get the credentials from the Facebook app.  If it makes sense for your site, you might have to support Facebook Connect.  If your like buttons are extra content and your site has nothing to do with Facebook, then I think this is the best you can do.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I was just checking if there is any other better ways to display your facebook page on mobile, but I guess iFrames is the way to go for now!